# ffmpeg screen capture using screen-capture-recorder cmd not working in vb

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg

I've started ffmpeg as process in VB but ffmpeg cmd for capturing alone is not working. My code is,I don't know how to solve the problem, if any help greatly appreciated

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\converter\bin\ffmpeg.exe"            
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-f dshow -i video=screen-capture-recorder screen.mp4"
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
proc.Start()
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? If you run the `ffmpeg` command manually does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes i did and the expected output came, and also i found an alternate solution and completed my task

Answer (score 0):

```
    This is my code

    Dim sAppPath As String
    Dim sCommand As String
    Dim sFilePath As String

    sCommand = AppSettings.Get("command")
    sFilePath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    'Full HD
    sAppPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\converter\bin\ffmpeg.exe " & sCommand & " " & sFilePath & "\RENDER\" & m_sFileName & ".mp4"
    WriteLog("Testing " & sCommand & " " & sFilePath & " " & sAppPath)
    'sAppPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\converter\bin\ffmpeg.exe -f dshow  -vcodec rawvideo -s 1920x1080  -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i video=screen-capture-recorder -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -qp 0 -tune zerolatency -vf fps=24 -framerate 24 -y" & " C:\Users\Bode20\Documents\RENDER\" & m_sFileName & ".mp4"
    ProcID = Shell(sAppPath, AppWinStyle.MinimizedFocus)
```